# Eclipse not working in 16.04

Tags: eclipse, 16.04

Eclipse was working as good as anything on 14.04. I did a clean install of 16.04 and installed Eclipse. But it runs a Java program only once after which it just hangs during subsequent attempts before I remove and reinstall it. I have tried many things, since in the beginning I needed CDT as well. Right now, I just want to remove everything related to eclipse and do a fresh install (remove all the configs and dependencies). Please note that I used Eclipse installer to install Eclipse and the eclipse icon image is also not appearing (the default ubuntu ? is appearing).

Comment: I have the same problem. I decided to install an older version (Luna), which is still better than indigo and have support for JDK-8. Maybe in meantime Ubuntu will provide the newest version in software repository.

Answer (score 116):

I had something the same with 16.04 and Eclipse Mars. I thought it had frozen but in fact it was running very, very slowly. The problem is the version of GTK+ 3, shipped with 16.04. Fortunately the solution is very easy. Open a terminal and then type `export SWT_GTK3=0`, then start Eclipse from the terminal. If that works, then a more persistent fix is to put the *2 lines below, as they appear* in your `eclipse.ini`:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

before the line:

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
```

The bug is filed with Ubuntu at [bug 1552764](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+bug/1552764)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for Java. CDT is still slow though. But good for now.

Comment: Also worked fine on a upgraded 16.04 (from 15.10). But java has according to top sometimes in idle 60% cpu usage

Comment: @Motte001 - thank for the information. I also see 60% CPU usage on start up, then it drops to about 10%. Maybe when they get round to fixing Ubuntu's GT3 module, it will drop the java usage.

Comment: worked for me too.

Comment: @NickT Thanks! Editing `eclipse.ini` solved my problem with [System Workbench for STM32](http://www.openstm32.org/System+Workbench+for+STM32) on Ubuntu 16.04x64

Comment: Excellent! Same problem appears in TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio 6.2.2, since it is Eclipse based. 
After: "features/jre.linux.gtk.x86_64.feature_1.8.0.u77/jre/bin" and before: "-vmargs" , adding the three lines: 
"--launcher.GTK_version", 
"2" and 
"--launcher.appendVmargs" in the Jaspersoft Studio.ini file solves this problem also.

Comment: @NickT is the bug removed now ?

Comment: Non of these solutions helped me :(

Comment: @NickT Nice answer. For anyone use Eclipse Mars and above, maybe you would like to install Webkit 1.0 to avoid the "The SWT Browser widget could not be created" error https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497188

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the tip.

I had to change required version of java from :

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

into

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
```

and remove this line as well :

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Happy coding !

Answer (score 3):

Edit `eclipse.desktop` as following:

```
Exec=env SWT_GTK3=0 eclipse
```

Answer (score 1):

My recomendation is that you install Eclipse Mars from the webpage:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php?release=mars

But first you have to install java8 (not java9 because Eclipse Mars doesn't work with that version). In Ubuntu you can do this with:
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jdk

And then .. and just if you have other java version, you have to select java8 with this command:
sudo update-alternatives --config java

Voilà! That worked for me! :)

Comment: I was having the same problem as the OP with Eclipse Mars which was installed before Ubuntu 16. NickT's answer resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

By starting the application from the command line (the terminal) it is sometimes possible to get more information about why the program fails to start. For example (assuming that eclipse is in your path, otherwise start it from the folder where it is installed/unpacked):

```
user@machine:~$ eclipse
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=256m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

In this case it looks like the line

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

in the file `eclipse.ini` is the problem. Simply remove that line (create a backup of the `eclipse.ini` file first) and try to start the program again.

Above solution worked on `Eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)` on a machine upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bamf/+bug/1532226) in Ubuntu 16.04. This affects not only eclipse but several other applications too.

Before the fix is released here is a quick fix that works. Open terminal and type

```
$ initctl restart unity-panel-service
```

This will bring back the Menus for the current session. But you may want to do this again if you restart your machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an error for `libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0` or `WTFCrash`, try installing `libwebkitgtk-3.0-0`:

`sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-3.0-0`