# Is the GTK3/SWT bug fixed with the Eclipse Neon release?

Tags: 16.04, java, eclipse, gtk

I made a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and I continued to install Eclipse Mars 4.2 as well. But every time I create a new project Eclipse hangs.

I found out that there is a bug reported for this at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=492371.

Will installing Eclipse Neon solve this issue? Any suggestions please?

Comment: I believe it is a bug with Ubuntu's implementation of GTK+3. There is a fix for Eclipse (tried it with Mars) described in my answer here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/761604/eclipse-not-working-in-16-04/761680#761680