# How can i create eclipse launcher icon with specified gtk?

Tags: launcher, eclipse, gtk, .desktop

To solve [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+bug/1552764) on the new release of Eclipse, most people use [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/761680/464430). It works fine when I run Eclipse using terminal or from the default folder (`/opt/eclipse/`), but when I lock Eclipse to the launcher or create a `.desktop` file and open the file, it returns back to its default GTK.

My `.desktop` file is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=Mars
Name=Eclipse
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Type=Application
Categories=IDE;Development
```

Note: on "Exec" I have also tried `/opt/eclipse/eclipse` but that has not solved my problem.

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTX-5m5EwhI&feature=youtu.be) a video for more description.

Comment: Have you already tried the "more persistent fix" in the linked answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem before. For some reason Eclipse creates a launcher icon on **~/.local/share/applications**. so i edit the default Eclipse **.desktop** file:

1. `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`.
2. in the line of **Exec** i comment the line.
3. and write `/opt/eclipse/eclipse`.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Make a script and put it in the "Exec=" line of the desktop file.

```
#!/bin/bash
export SWT_GTK3=0
eclipse
```

Comment: Hello wjandrea , thanks for helping but i think their's no difference between running `/opt/eclipse/eclipse` and running link file using bash script anyway i try this solution don't solve my problem.