# Problems with eclipse mars 2 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, eclipse

I would like to know if someone has problems with Eclipse mars in Ubuntu 16.04  like i have.

I have eclipse mars installed in Ubuntu 16.04 when i try to check for updates the window wizard does not show up, and when i want to install new software when i choose all available sites it does not show any option (it stills pending... without any result), i tried to install it again but nothing changed.
Is there any incompatibility between eclipse mars and this version of Ubuntu ??

**Note:** I upgraded to Eclipse Neon and this reolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+bug/1552764) but here is an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/761680/464430) almost cover this bug

1. Goto eclipse directory (`/opt/eclipse`).
2. append `--launcher.GTK_version` `2` to **eclipse.ini**[image]
3. Save and run eclipse using terminal or the original directory

> **Note**: if you create a launcher before and open it will not detect **GTK** according my previous [Question](https://askubuntu.com/q/783695/464430)