# Ubuntu 16 : Eclipse marse : Unable to add apache tomcat

Tags: 16.04, eclipse, tomcat

I am unable to add tomcat server in eclipse, could you please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well its because you might already have one conflicting. You could accomplish this via

> Tools > preference > Server

On the right side list delete the one already have and add a new tomcat server.
That's it

Comment: No There is no server is added previously , this is fresh new work space

Comment: ok. Then add a new server following the above options and see are you able to add server.

Answer (score 0):

This is bug with ubuntu 16 I found in forum

Solution :  Add ( in eclipse.ini ) file

> `--launcher.GTK_version 2`

before `--launcher.appendVmargs`

Reference [Eclipse not working in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761604/eclipse-not-working-in-16-04)