# SWT control is not working in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, gtk

I am working on an Eclipse project. Some of its SWT control is not working properly in Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04.

I found by searching online that this issue is because of the latest GTK versions. The fix is executing the following command before starting the application via terminal `export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true`.

This worked for all of my colleagues but not my machine (Ubuntu 14.04). Why did it fail and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. Normaly, it is solved (for me in Ubuntu 16.10) by

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

before

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
```

See also: [Eclipse not working in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761604/eclipse-not-working-in-16-04) If it does not work, it would be helpful to add your eclipse version, or maybe to try a newer/older version.