# Eclipse Error log file generated on Exit

Tags: 16.04, java, eclipse

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Eclipse Oxygen(September) seems to work fine when I want to edit Java files but when I close eclipse. A log file with error is generated in /home/user/

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3fbd7a8c4c, pid=28399, tid=0x00007f4050387700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3-b11)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18+0xd45c4c]  WTFCrash+0x1c
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Its followed by this error message from Ubuntu

[image]

Comment: try `sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-3.0-0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is error log running Eclipse Oxygen.1a on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f6f8cc93c4c, pid=10184, tid=0x00007f7000304700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_151-b12) (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.151-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18+0xd45c4c]  WTFCrash+0x1c
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

It seems that the error is not only related to Ubuntu, but to an issue with Eclipse and GTK Webkit.

That issue is being tracked in the Eclipse's bugtracker as well as in the Webkit one.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=522733

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=177577

Workaround:
As with previous issues found with GTK3, a possible workaround is to force Eclipse to switch back to GTK2 by adding this in the eclipse.ini file (before the "--launcher.appendVmargs").

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

Refer this [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/761680/372437)